# Unable to connect to Snowflake using snowsql on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to use snowsql on my Amazon EC2 instance, and I have been trying to log in. I ran this in the terminal:

`snowsql -a [account_name] -u [user_name]`

I then get this prompt in the terminal, and I input my password:
`Password:`

After a while, I get this error message:

```
250003 (n/a): Failed to execute request: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='https', port=443): 
Max retries exceeded with url: 
//[XXXXXXXXX].us-east-2.aws.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?request_id=XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXX 
(Caused by NewConnectionError('<snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f4a86f25438>: 
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',))

If the error message is unclear, enable logging using -o log_level=DEBUG 
and see the log to find out the cause. Contact support for further help.

Goodbye!
```

Does anyone know what the issue is? Is it likely an issue with my EC2 instance or with Snowflake?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an issue with EC2 instance side.

Answer (score 0):

Seems dns issue, as it says name resolution error. Try adding entry to /etc/hosts